# Can i have a private / user-specific etc folder?

Tags: environment-variables, user-profiles, bashrc, folder-redirection, files-folders

I am often fiddling about with software built from source, which i install in `$HOME/.local`. To make it run, i have to export various variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But i do not want to have to export them all manually *every* time i want to use some of that software. Most of them can be exported in my `$HOME/.profile` and `.bashrc` file, but not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This one can only be changed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. But i do not want to modify root's files. So my question is : Can i create a folder in my home folder / anywhere, which will automatically be treated as a second `/etc` folder, or is there an environment variable which i can set to point to such a directory ?

Comment: I think you can find the answer here - <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts>

Comment: no sorry @HareshShah , i want to do it just by exporting some environment variable. Or can i maybe put such files in `$HOME/.config` ?

Comment: Try to see if [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104511/17660) works for you. Otherwise, you could use [libnss_homehosts](https://github.com/bAndie91/libnss_homehosts).

Comment: @harrymc sorry, but both links are only specific for the /etc/hosts file, but i want to have a private etc folder (or any folder where i can create ld.so.conf, hosts, etc.). Basically like the $PATH environment variable, so that the programs that use for example ld.so.conf look in each directory listed in e.g. $ETC_PATH for a ld.so.conf, and append the files together

Comment: or maybe the other way round : can i place a ld.so.conf file in $HOME/.conf and then make it as if i had placed the same file in /etc, and if yes how ?

Comment: Why can't you add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bash_profile`? See other methods in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux). But read the warnings in [this post](https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180).

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH works for terminal applications alright, but what about desktop apps ? In .profile, export LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effects for security reasons. @harrymc

Comment: For a particular command you could do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... ; command`. What is your usage method if not in terminal?

Comment: @harrymc for example if i built glade from source, i put the .desktop file for it into .local/share/applications, and it appears in my menu. But it wont start, since the libraries it needs are installed in .local/lib/. But please note that LD_LIBRARY_PATH was only an example. My question was more generic for _all_ config files in /etc (even if there were an environment variable for each setting, you would end up adding hundreds and thousands of exports to your .profile)

Comment: @harrymc modifying the .desktop files is not an option, since i would have to do that again every time i update it by redownloading the new sources and rebuilding them.

Comment: You could use the [unshare](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) command ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242830/17660)) to mount any file you like. You may also use the heavier solution of `chroot`.

Comment: @harrymc 1. i already read that question, but will both hosts files be read (the original one and the one in the home folder) ? 2. I have to use sudo again, what i do not like. But, if thats the only solution, i have to use that. 3. This wont work from the desktop, again.

Comment: 1. The file is replaced. 3. You mean from a desktop icon? That depends on the icon.

Comment: ok thanks @harrymc for your time, but one last question : It is not possible to for example put `export ETC_DIRS=/etc:/home/user/etc` (or something similar) into my `.profile` file, and then have the e.g. `ld.so.conf` from `/etc` _and_ `/home/user/etc` together ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to automatically merge files. For `unshare` etc you would need to build your own replacement files, based on the originals. Would you like an answer about that?

Comment: yes please, i will accept it, then, as there seems to be no better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the
[unshare command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html)
to mount and replace any file or folder you like.
There is also the solution of `chroot`, but it's much heavier to implement.

A good example is found in the post
[Can I create a user-specific hosts file to complement /etc/hosts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts)

The [answer by frielp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242830/17660)
is a good example for replacing the `hosts` file:

> Private mountspaces created with the `unshare` command can be used to
> provide  a private /etc/hosts file to a shell process and any
> subsequent child processes started from that shell.
>
> ```
> # Start by creating your custom /etc/hosts file
> [user] cd ~
> [user] cat >my_hosts <<EOF
> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
> 127.0.0.1 news.bbc.co.uk
> EOF
>
> [user] sudo unshare --mount
> # We're now running as root in a private mountspace. 
> # Any filesystem mounts performed in this private mountspace
> # are private to this shell process and its children
>
> # Use a bind mount to install our custom hosts file over /etc/hosts
> [root] mount my_hosts /etc/hosts --bind
>
> [root] cat /etc/hosts
> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
> 127.0.0.1 news.bbc.co.uk
>
> [root] exec su - appuser
>
> [appuser] # Run your app here that needs a custom /etc/hosts file
>
> [appuser] ping news.bbc.co.uk
> PING news.bbc.co.uk (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
> 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
> ^C
> --- news.bbc.co.uk ping statistics ---
> 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.044/0.062/0.018 ms
> ```

The `unshare` command replaces files or folders.
So if you only wish to *add* to some files in `/etc`, you would need to build
the replacement files by appending your data to the original contents.